Windows broke my installation, mokutil --set-sbat-policy delete doesn't seem to make any changes. Am I forced to keep SecureBoot off?
August 13th update of Windows triggered a SBAT error: security policy violation, like in the following question:
Windows aug. 13 update broke my Ubuntu system!
I followed the instructions and get the following (everything executed as root):
# mokutil --list-sbat-revocations 
sbat,1,2022052400
grub,2

# mokutil --set-sbat-policy delete

# mokutil --list-sbat-revocations 
sbat,1,2022052400
grub,2

It seems like grub,2 should be gone from the list. Is my only option to keep SecureBoot disabled?
I am familiar with the command line, but have zero familiarity with dealing with SecureBoot, since I've never had to deal with it.

Not sure what is happening but I would say that after you make the delete statement you have to reboot before you relist. Changes to the UEFI happen during the boot process.

I see! I'll try to relist and re-enable secureboot

After rebooting, grub is still in my list but secureboot works. My best guess is grub is a more recent one than what is listed by sbat policy?

Answer from a Canonical Engineering Manager: https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/sbat-self-check-failed-mitigating-the-impact-of-shim-15-7-revocation-on-the-ubuntu-boot-process-for-devices-running-windows/47378

As said by @david, you need to do the mokutil --set-sbat-policy delete and then reboot. Then you can re-enable secure boot on your BIOS.
I hope this helps!
